# Whitelist USB drivers(kernel modules)

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, kernel-module

I am looking for a way to configure a whitelist of allowed usb drivers on Fedora. All other USB drivers should not be loaded. What's the simplest way to do so? I know how to blacklist drivers using a config file, but how do I achieve the opposite? The whitelisting of a preselection of USB drivers?

Comment: Uh...Blacklist all but the ones you want loaded. How would the kernel know which ones were USB drivers? Would a USB builtin card reader count as a USB driver? The kernel doesn't know what the developers put in the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, perhaps a simple script that gets the list of currently loaded modules(using lsmod) and all modules(how do we do this? only by using ls on the directory of those modules?) => then it just blacklists everything that's not loaded at the moment(or it could even move those files to some other folder to avoid accidental loading by dependencies/etc). Now if someone has that script it would be nice of them to share it.